# Pre boot authentication for Android phones

Tags: authentication, mobile, android

is there any way to have pre boot authentication on android phones? It would be nice if it would work with YubikeyONE's one time password mode.

Comment: Probably yes but what for ? If somebody stole your phone and could not run it he would probably flash it and reinstall android, or read raw data from mem.

Comment: This site may also be able to assist you: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @fatfredyy To make your private data inaccessible of course. The whole point of encryption is that once the device is out of your hands you have lost device, ok we'll have to live with that, but at least your private data can't be accessed. Which is currently not the case with Android...

Answer (score 3):

What would the use be of preboot authentication when Android doesn't support full disk encryption for all files and folders? none.

Answer (score 1):

**No**,

As by the time of me writing this there isn't, at least not to the extent of my research capabilities.

Some of the matter's underlying problems are explained quite nicely [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17918). From there we can also see that the disk *can* be accessed via `ADB`. And for example in recovery mode you can use [ADB to the fullest](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1957423)

I'll have to say I find this kind of frustrating and I totally agree with the people in the Google Group, what is the point of the encryption if it's... well... disabled as soon as you turn the device on. As Lucas already hinted: Android does [not have "Full-Disk-Encryption"](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/06/29/some-thoughts-about-androids-full-disk-encryption/) (really interesting blog-post) as most people understand it but only encrypts the `/data` folder.

However I imagine that on the level of custom ROMs where people also implement boot animations and other neat tricks this should be possible. I think it requires major tweaks on the linux os level, though and I haven't found anything useful yet while researching.

I assume the target group for something this tricky is not large enough (yet)